# How to create an new account on a bitcoind server

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, server

What is the correct rpc call to start a new account on a bitcoind server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do one of the following:

- create an address using `getnewaddress`
- send some coins with a `move` command

Those commands will automatically create the target account if it doesn't exist.

Comment: This can be done in one step with `getnewaddress <account>` [API call list](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list)

Comment: @NickODell I meant he could do one thing or the other, I'll reword